# jQuery open fancybox if condition is met

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have an anchor which opens a fancybox. I want the fancybox to open only when a selection from a selectbox is made.

I found out that binding a click event to the anchor with preventDefault or return false does not prevent the fancybox from opening. 
I did find out a way to stop the fancybox from opening. Now I have:

HTML

```
<div>
<a id="brasil" href="<?php echo $this->url( array( "module" => "amodule", "controller"  => "acontroller", "action" => "soccer"))?>" class="someclass bigfancybox"><?=$this->translate('soccer')?></a>
</div>
```

The dimensions (width, height, etc defined in fancybox.js) of the fancybox are tied to the classname "bigfancybox" of the anchor.

In jQuery I have a check if a selection on match_id is made:

```
jQuery("#brasil").fancybox({
onStart: function() {
var matchid = jQuery('#match_id').val();
if(matchid == '')
    {
        alert(selectmatchmessage);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

This all works fine except that if the condition is met, now the fancybox opens in default dimensions and is not opening as an iframe as it would without the jQuery condition. Is there a way to check a condition first before opening a fancybox in an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to bind a `click` *event* to your `#brasil` selector (or to your `.bigfancybox` selector if you prefer) rather than fancybox.

Then, validate the condition after the *event* and fire fancybox programmatically **if** the condition is met otherwise do nothing (return `false`) like :

```
jQuery("#brasil").on("click", function () {
    var matchid = jQuery('#match_id').val();
    if (matchid !== '') {
        // condition is NOT empty, so fire fancybox
        jQuery.fancybox({
            // fancybox API options
            href: this.href,
            type: "iframe"
        });
    };
    return false; // prevent default and stop propagation
}); // on click
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ycAE5/)**

**NOTE** :

The fiddle uses fancybox v1.3.4 but the code would seamlessly work for fancybox v2.x too, just make sure you use the right API options for each version.

Comment: Okay this works well. However I will have to copy the fancybox options into this function and can not refer to my standard bigfancybox in fancybox.js which I call with class bigfancybox, but that is absolutely acceptable. Thanks mate!